# Prestashop 1.6. Multilanguage site - not redirecting to the correct theme template

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a site with 3 languages - Spanish, French and English.

Redirecting to Spanish and French (url `/es/` or `/fr/`) is OK. The site redirects to the correct template.

But when I redirect to English (url `/gb/`) the site doesn't load the correct theme template and goes to another theme template.

To clarify, the language is loaded correctly but shows other template. All languages goes to "SP Good" template but the English site (url `/gb/`) goes to another template and the language is correctly loaded.

Has anyone had this experience and/or know how to fix it?

Comment: Edited text for clarity and readability

Comment: there are two different english languages in prestashop, ENGLISH GB en_gb (british) and ENGLISH en_us (united states)  the first has /gb/ the other /en/ be sure to use the right url to redirect

Comment: Tedinoz, thanks for the edition but there is no English template, all languages goes to the same template less the english one that load other.

Comment: Sim1-81, the /en/ redirect to /gb/ so it works properly